# Emacs 23 on Ubuntu - menus between Tools and Help are broken

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I have used succesfully used for some time 
GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.18.0)
on Ubuntu 9.10. With all kinds of plugins and additions.

Now I have installed a completely new Ubuntu, that's 11.04, and I installed most of the emacs and related emacs plugins with apt-get.

This is what I have installed.

```
i A emacs23                                                                                    - The GNU Emacs editor (with GTK+ user interface)
i A emacs23-bin-common                                                                         - The GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture dependent files
i A emacs23-common                                                                             - The GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture independent infrastructure
v   emacs23-gtk                                                                                -
i A emacsen-common
```

And my version now is:
GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.4)
 of 2011-04-04 on crested, modified by Debian

The problem is, that on when I enter any mode (css, sgml, org, sql, c, text, etc), whatever menus I have between Tools and Help do not show. So the main menu item shows (like SQL in sql mode), but when I mouseover it, it does not contain any items.

First, I thought is one of the *.el files I have in my .emacs.d or I blame it on pymacs rope ropemode ropemacs etc. But then I deleted all from my .emacs file and my .emacs.d folder and I have the same strange thing.
What is extremely weird, is that sometimes, I don't know how, when I start emacs, the problem is gone. This is like one in 50 tries. I first thought I did something (like when I uninstalled magit), and blame it on that. But then I closed and opened my emacs again, without modifying anything and the menus were broken again.

No that I installed back my .emacs .emacs.d and my plugins, since it's not their fault, I have for example on scratch buffer a Lisp-Interaction menu beginning with "Complete Lisp symbol" and then a YASnippet empty menu.
If I switch to a .py file, the first menu after the Tools menu is IM-Python, which in fact has the sub-menu items that Lisp-Interaction menu has. So when I hover on IM-Python I get "Complete Lisp Symbol", "Indent-or-Pretty print", etc. and then the rest of menus Python, Yasnippet, Rope are empty. And the last menu, Help, is good again.

I really don't know what should I try more, or how to go further and debug, I've been fighting with it for hours.

PS: oh yeah, so now I discovered an answer on stackoverflow for a similar issue, so when I hit F10 (menu-bar-open) the menu fixes, the submenu items appear correctly.
But when I open a new file and want to use the menu again, it's broken and have to hit F10 again and it works. So it's not so bad after all :) but anyway, if you have a clue please let me know.

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: Why would someone need menus on Emacs ? They kill productivity. Learn about `M-x` and `C-h`. Look [there](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/LCSR-Computing/some-docs/emacs-chart.html).

Comment: I have many shortcuts and commands I use with M-x. But for example, in IM-Python menu I can navigate to any class or method I need in python. There are various plugins like Yasnippet or different major-modes that have useful commands there, and it's very quick to take a look and use the menu or learn what's available. I'm not using for my daily commands which I've assigned shortcuts to.

Comment: thanks for the F10 tip - that works for me (temporarily)

Answer (score 0):

Try and duplicate the issue with a plain-vanilla emacs.  To do that, startup emacs like this:

```
$ emacs -q --no-site-init
```

It should work as expected.  If it does, then make a copy of your .emacs file and in the copy, delete half of it, then restart emacs normally.  If the problem is there, then cut down your .emacs by half again; if it's not there, startup with the other half of the original .emacs file.  Lather, rinse, repeat until you find the offending code that mucks everything up.

If it does *not* work when `emacs -q --no-site-init` is called, then there's something wonky going on in the interaction between your emacs binary and the window manager, which will be a *lot* tougher to track down.